# Union of multiple columns in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have the table like this

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4
A       X       ADesc   XDesc
A       Y       ADesc   YDesc
B       Y       BDesc   YDesc
C       Z       CDesc   ZDesc
C       W       CDesc   WDesc
```

Assume Col1 & Col2 are codes, Col3 & Col4 are their respective descriptions. Meaning Col3 is the description for Col1. Similarly, Col4 is the desc for Col2.
I want to find all the distinct codes(individual codes, not the pairs) and their descriptions

The result should be

```
A  ADesc
B  BDesc
C  CDesc
X  XDesc
Y  YDesc
Z  ZDesc
W  WDesc
```

How to write the query. I'm thinking something like this but it doesn't work

```
select Col1 as Code, Col2 as Desc from <tableA>
union
select Col3, Col4 from <tableA>;
```

Also, not sure how to do distinct. Ex, there are two entries of A, C, Y but I just need one.

Comment: "*it doesn't work*" - can you be just a *bit* more specific? What happened when you ran this code? Why didn't it meet your expectation? See [ask]

Comment: Why are you using col2 as desc? Your description is in col3.  
Your query should be like :

select distinct Col1 as Code, Col3 as Desc from <tableA>
union
select distinct Col2, Col4 from <tableA>;

Comment: Just a guess: `SELECT DISTINCT Col1, Col3 FROM tableA UNION SELECT DISTINCT Col2, Col4 FROM tableA`

Comment: @Abra, no need for select distinct when you do UNION, since UNION itself removes all duplicates. (UNION ALL keeps them.)

Answer (score 2):

Try Something like below:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Col1 AS Code, Col3 AS Description
FROM YourTable
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Col2 AS Code, Col4 AS Description
FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: No need for select distinct when you do UNION, since UNION itself removes all duplicates. (UNION ALL keeps them.)

Comment: Also no need to use column names in the second query. They will just be ignored. When using `UNION`, the result will get the column names from the first query.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, codes columns( Col1,Col2) listed in first SELECT and description columns (Col3, Col4) are listed in second SELECT in the UNION query causing to return different result. Changing the columns in the SELECT will give you desired result.

```
SELECT Col1 AS Code, Col3 AS [Desc] FROM MyTable
UNION
SELECT Col2, Col4 FROM MyTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNPIVOT` to only query the table once:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT code, description
FROM   table_name
UNPIVOT (
  (code, description) FOR type IN (
    (Col1, Col3) AS '1+3',
    (Col2, Col4) AS '2+4'
  )
);
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (col1, col2, col3, col4) AS
SELECT 'A', 'X', 'ADesc', 'XDesc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'Y', 'ADesc', 'YDesc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'Y', 'BDesc', 'YDesc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'Z', 'CDesc', 'ZDesc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'W', 'CDesc', 'WDesc' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| CODE | DESCRIPTION |
| --- | --- |
| A | ADesc |
| X | XDesc |
| Y | YDesc |
| B | BDesc |
| C | CDesc |
| Z | ZDesc |
| W | WDesc |

You could also use:

```sql
SELECT col1 AS code, col3 AS description FROM table_name
UNION
SELECT col2, col4 FROM table_name;
```

Which gives the same output; however, it will query the table twice (once for each `SELECT`) so may be less efficient.

The fiddle below contains the `EXPLAIN PLAN`s for both queries showing that `UNPIVOT` uses a single `TABLE ACCESS FULL` whereas using `UNION` has two `TABLE ACCESS FULL`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GMLRWG8A)